# Finding the value of abc

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

The ratio of the six-digit numbers $abcabc$ and $ababab$ is 55:54. Find the
values of the digits $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: $ababab$ is divisible by $10101$ and $54$

Answer (score 1):

$abcabc = abc\times 1001 = abc\times 7\times11\times 13$

$ababab = ab\times 10101 = ab\times 3\times 7\times 13\times 37$

$\frac{abcabc}{ababab} = \frac{abc}{ab}\frac{11}{3\times 37} = \frac{55}{54} \implies \frac{abc}{ab} = \frac{185}{18}$

... which is conveniently the form we need (we don't need to multiply both sides by some constant to make the digits match up). So $abcabc = 185185$ and $ababab = 181818$.

Comment: To be complete, you also need to show there are no other solutions of form $\ (abc_{10}, ab_{10}) = (185k, 18k)\ $

Answer (score 0):

The easy way -- from the problem statement

$$5405400A+540540B+54054c=555550A+55555B
$$
This gives $$
54054C = 150150A + 15015B
$$
The RHS is divisible by $5$ so $C$ is divisible by $5$ so $C=5$.

If $C=5$ the LHS is $270270 < 150150\cdot 2$ so $A=1$.

Finally $15015B = 270270-150150 = 120120$
so $B=8$.